# How can I organize these CSS Selectors more efficiently? I want a CSS selector to apply to elements that have ids assigned as well

Tags: css, css-selectors, code-organization

Sorry for the poor wording on the title.
I wanted to know if there was a way to have a CSS file do something like the following code, and have background color apply to all my table cells with ids. -

```
td {
background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

#OtherTableCell {
border: 1px solid black;
}

#AnotherTableCell {
font-weight: bold;
}

#OneMoreTableCell {
width: 5%;
}
```

Is there a way to do that, or do I just have to write it like

```
#OtherTableCell {
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

#AnotherTableCell {
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

#OneMoreTableCell {
width: 5%;
background-color: #d3d3d3;
}
```

Comment: Keyword: Attribute selector.

Comment: what does it do when you try it? CSS or Cascading Style Sheets by design "cascade" Your Top code sample should work. You may want to look into [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and its effect on css

Comment: @happymacarts 
It... works like that by default.
*sigh* Now I'm a little embarrased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google [OOCSS](https://www.google.com/search?q=oocss&rlz=1CDGOYI_enUS745US745&oq=ooc&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0j5.1959j0j7&hl=en-US&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) (Object-oriented CSS) for guidelines on how to create "objects" in CSS to organize your CSS more efficiently. You simply need to follow DRY principles as well so styles aren't repeated unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks!
I need to get better at researching these before I ask for help.

Comment: Not a problem - sometimes it can be hard to know what to even search for. This question has multiple answers as well, OOCSS is [just one paradigm to consider.](https://fyxerz.gitbooks.io/final-year-project/content/coding_prep/css.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are many answers to this question.  There are some complete guides out there that will help.

My favorite was this one: https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/

There are many ways to group styles by rows or columns and titles.  It all depends on what exactly you want to do.